# Unable to serve files from Windows folder using Jetty

Tags: java, servlets, io, cross-platform

I modified [the embedded-jetty project](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java) to create [a stand-alone jsp-viewer](https://github.com/fatso83/jsp-viewer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fatso83/jspviewer/Main.java) that should be able to serve any directory containing jsps, not just the ones embedded in a jar file. *The resulting jar works fine on macOS and Linux.*

What I discovered is that *it does not work on Windows* - for some reason that escapes me, although the logs indicate that it resolved the directory just fine. I have enabled the `"dirAllowed"` property to list directory contents, yet I consistently get this error no matter the directory or file:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Not Found
```

I ripped out a lot of unneeded code, but I believe the main difference between my project on the demo project from Jetty is this diff that shows how my project references a `webroot` property as the directory to serve, instead of a hard coded path in the jar file in the original

```
>         String userDir = System.getProperty("webroot");
>         String webroot = (userDir != null && userDir.length() > 0)? userDir : ".";
>         webroot = Paths.get(webroot).toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
```

and this

```
<         URL indexUri = this.getClass().getResource(WEBROOT_INDEX);
>         URL indexUri = new URL("file://" + webroot);
```

Is there something about the `file://` syntax where I should handle it differently on Windows?

**Output from console when running on macOS**

```
./jsp-viewer/view-jsp /tmp
2017-01-02 15:53:50.456:INFO::main: Logging initialized @124ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
jan 02, 2017 3:53:50 PM com.github.fatso83.jspviewer.Main defaultServletHolder
INFO: Base URI: file:/tmp
2017-01-02 15:53:50.574:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-01-02 15:53:50.737:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2017-01-02 15:53:50.737:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2017-01-02 15:53:50.740:INFO:oejs.session:main: Scavenging every 660000ms
2017-01-02 15:53:50.756:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6d8a00e3{/,file:///tmp/,AVAILABLE}
2017-01-02 15:53:50.779:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@457e2f02{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2017-01-02 15:53:50.779:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @451ms
jan 02, 2017 3:53:50 PM com.github.fatso83.jspviewer.Main getServerUri
INFO: Server URI: http://localhost:8080/
```

**Output on Windows (Mingw)**

```
$ ./jsp-viewer/view-jsp /tmp/
2017-01-02 16:12:15.541:INFO::main: Logging initialized @266ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
jan 02, 2017 4:12:18 PM com.github.fatso83.jspviewer.Main defaultServletHolder
INFO: Base URI: file://C:/Users/SA_CAR~1.KOP/AppData/Local/Temp/2
2017-01-02 16:12:18.106:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-01-02 16:12:18.449:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2017-01-02 16:12:18.450:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2017-01-02 16:12:18.454:INFO:oejs.session:main: Scavenging every 600000ms
2017-01-02 16:12:18.475:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@24a67{/,file://C/Users/SA_CAR~1.KOP/AppData/Local/Temp/2,AVAILABLE}
2017-01-02 16:12:18.515:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@feb3fa{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2017-01-02 16:12:18.530:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @3261ms
jan 02, 2017 4:12:18 PM com.github.fatso83.jspviewer.Main getServerUri
INFO: Server URI: http://localhost:8080/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in manually creating Uris and Urls. By delegating this chore to Java I got URLs that worked in all operating systems. As suspected, the error was present in one of the lines mentioned above:

I exchanged

```
URL indexUri = new URL("file://" + webroot);
```

for

```
Paths.get(webroot).toAbsolutePath().toUri().toURL()
```

and everything started working on Windows as well. Jan Bartel on the [[jetty-users] mailing list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg07464.html) came up with the answer.